# Init some static resources in codebehind and have access to them in XAML (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a big image that I load to memory once ,split this image to multiple `BitmapImage` and from this point on there will be no changes to those images.

With this part i'm done: Initializing this list right after `InitializeComponent();` of the Window partial class..

The only problem is , I cannot access to this list from my XAML file. I have tired so many different ways described online but none worked.

I am asking this question as a general issue and not a specific error I get cause there might be a better way to achieve the same purpose using C#/wpf mechanisms that i'm not aware of.. (i'm mainly doing java)

Thanks!

**EDIT1:** (after implementing @Janne Matikainen solution)

Now I get this error (not positive its related)
[image]

where the Uri for the image I use is :

```
new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/myimage.bmp", UriKind.Absolute)
```

and the folder `Images` lays in the project root.

Is it related to our issue?

**EDIT 2** :
The warning for the URI is just a warning - It basically says it cannot find the URI since the link to the bitmaps will be built in runtime , and it cannot "find" it during compile time..

Comment: have you tried use binding?

Comment: Doable with bindings or manipulating element properties from code-behind (using their `x:Name`).

Comment: this is not related to the original issue. It's another problem. You will get the same result if you do 'SomeImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(theUri)` in codebehind

Comment: Can I use something like:  new Uri(@"C:\aaa\bbb\ccc\myimage.bmp") ?? is it a valid uri?

Comment: if I cannot fix this - I will try your solution

Comment: Make sure your images have build action as Resource, that syntax for the pack uri should be ok.

Comment: you right - it IS ok.. so I guess its just C# 's way to warn me :)  btw they are setup with build action = resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a static view model that you can bind from within your view(s). Then you load the image and split it within the private constructor and expose the Image or collection, depending on the binding approach you take.

```
public class StaticImageViewModel
{
    private static readonly Lazy<StaticImageViewModel> Lazy = new Lazy<StaticImageViewModel>(() => new StaticImageViewModel());
    private List<BitmapImage> images;

    private StaticImageViewModel()
    {
        this.images = new List<BitmapImage>
            {
                new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Image1.png"))
            };
    }

    public static StaticImageViewModel Instance
    {
        get { return Lazy.Value; }
    }

    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            return this.images[0];
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can bind from this static viewmodel like this, you just need to make a valueconverter or such to get image with specific name/index from your dictionary/list.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:StaticImageViewModel.Instance}, Path=Image}"></Image>
```

Comment: It could be shortened to *use binding* (not necessarily using static property on which you put too much accent in your answer).

Comment: For sure this code can be included to the views viewmodel, but if these images are to be shared between multiple views, then this might be good approach, instead of wrapping the data within multiple viewmodels.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have 2 questions : 1. regarding the code itself, Source= must be singleton?    2. regarding Path=Image  , if I want to access another, i need to setup a new setter for example for this.images[5] .. ?

Comment: If you assign a viewmodel for the windows datacontext, then you can bind to that instead of a singleton. You need to bind to the collection and use a valueconverter to get specified item from that collection. It all kinda depends on if these images are just for this window or others as well.

Comment: Again, thanx. i'm checking this solution now :)

Comment: I think this is incorrect use of ViewModel pattern. ViewModel's responsibility is to expose data Model (Model = data and business logic) in such way that is easily consumable from view and vice versa. Just rename `StaticImageViewModel` to  something else and it will be ok

Comment: Also the URI is invalid. Images does not have namespace, so how can you specify namespace in URI? maybe youv'e meant assemblyname

Comment: Yes, that is correct, its not namespace but the assembly from where to search for.

Comment: how can I know the right URI ? where can I find my assemblyname ?

Answer (score 2):

You should not create resource dynamically. If you do, it has to be done before you call `InitializeCompontent()` and you need to access the resource using `{DynamicResource ResourceKey}` markup extension.

You can use **Binding** with **RelativeSource** to access properties defined in code behind:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyBitmapSources, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}" />
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> MyBitmapSources { get; private set; }

   public MainWindow()
   {
       MyBitmapSources = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
       InitializeComponent();

       var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
       bitmapImage.BeginInit();
       //set uri, or streamsource here
       bitmapImage.EndInit();


       MyBitmapSources.Add(bitmapImage);
   }
}
```

However, if you use binding, you should initialize the properties before you call `InilializeComponent()`. Otherwise you need to notify UI that the property has changed. Or in our case, that the collection has changed. I have used `ObservableCollection`, because it notifies UI about changes automatically.

**EDIT:**
If you want to share the BitmapImage between multiple views, just use singleton pattern or similar:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> MyBitmapSources 
   { 
      get { return MySingleton.Instance.MyBitmapSources; }
   }
```

or you can store the collection in application resources:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> MyBitmapSources 
   { 
      get { return (ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>)Application.Current.Resources["MyBitmapSources"]; }
      set { Application.Current.Resources["MyBitmapSources"] = value; } 
   }
```

Comment: But you create resources dynamically at runtime, but StaticResource is checked at compile time. You should use binding for this scenario

Comment: see @Janne Matikainen solution. he state I can access those "statics" after init as i need to do.. I think dynamic resources are mainly for reloads.. no ?

Comment: no, purpose of dynamic resources is something else. Reload has nothing to do with it. @Janne Matikainen's solution works but I prefer the mine, see edit